# "globstar" equivalent in dash (Debian Almquist Shell)

Tags: filesystem, dash-shell, wildcards

I am using `/bin/dash` on a project, but I have need for `**/filename.ext` to have recursive behavior (i.e. `globstar` enabled in `bash`).

Is `globstar` available in `dash`? Is there a similar feature or alternative mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

From looking through the manpage, globstar is not available in Dash, and there is no similar feature. Dash doesn't even support arrays, so working with filenames is difficult.

The closest I can think of is making a list of filenames, using e.g. `find`, however filenames that contain newline characters would muck up the list, so you could do a check for them first with

```
find . -print0 | grep -zPq '\n'
```

which will return success if it finds any, and failure if it doesn't.

Or depending on your needs, you could put `find . -print0` in a pipeline with whatever commands you need to run, or output to a file then parse the file.

Comment: I don't use Dash very often, so if anyone is more familiar with it and knows a better way, I'm all ears.